# High cpu usage on youtube

Tags: hardware-acceleration

When playing videos on youtube the cpu increases up to 100% while in everyday use it stays around 15%.

In windows when playing videos on youtube the cpu usage is between 20 and 30%
I think it's a driver problem or graphics acceleration problem.

My Hardware

- **CPU:** Intel core I3 4005U 1.70GHz 2 cores 4 Threads
- **GPU:** Intel HD 4400
- **RAM:** 8 GB

Neofetch:

[image: Neofetch]

Ubuntu Htop:

[image: Ubuntu Htop]

Windows Task Manager:

[image: Windows Task Manager]

Thanks for the help

Comment: What is your web browser ?

Comment: i tried firefox, chrome, microsoft edge, brave and opera

Comment: I had a similar issue with my old PC (Pentium Duo) 4GB RAM and displayed similar symptoms to yours. I tried all types of browsers without any success - and, yes, enabled hardware accelaration as well. Finally I found that it was to do with the CPU heating up excessively so I removed the heat sink and cleaned up the CPU surface and   applied new thermal paste and this fixed the problem. Unlikely, that this will be the case in your situation but may be worthwhile giving it a good clean to make sure CPU heating up is not the cause.